# Change a link to a standard paragraph with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I have a list that is being built dynamically and is using some links to populate the data. The problem is I do not want the data to act like a link but it is coming as a link (a) and I want to change it on load to a (p) to remove any link functionality but I need to retain the href tag. Basically, is there a way to change just the HTML tag on load without having to empty and append the entire content block?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: There's no need to convert to another tag, unless you have a reason for wanting to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will make your a tags not clickable, but they still retain all attributes

Answer (score 0):

You could try to prevent the click event on those links and change cursor to preserve the A tag there along with any CSS that you might need from it (or replace that formatting with a paragraph-like one):

**JS:**

```
$('a').on('click', function() {return false;});
```

**CSS:**

```
a {cursor: default;}
```

In addition, you can [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) those links inside paragraphs to actually build up that P tag, if you really need to:

```
$('a').wrap('<p></p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be wiser to simply add "onclick=return false;" ? Href is not valid attribute to P - it's sematically wrong. Alternatively You could change element to p and put it in data-href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.specific_link_class').each(function(idx, el){

  $( this ).replaceWith( "<p data-href='" + $(this).attr('href') +"'>" + $( this ).text() + "</p>" );


});
```

> this will change all the links with specific class( change the class with appropriate selector)  to the p tags, with href as  data-href attribute of the new p tag.

Answer (score 0):

On a different note to my previous answer, you can preserve the HREF part of your links as a data attribute if you do the following:

```
$('a').each(
    var e = $(this);
    e.replaceWith('<p data-href="' + e.attr('href') + '">' + e.html() + '</p>');
});
```

To access that HREF, you'd later do:

```
$('p').data('href');
```